# UTF-8 Issue, don't know where

Tags: utf-8

```
$ sudo locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  de_DE.UTF-8...cannot open locale definition file `de_DE': No such file or directory
 done
Generation complete.$ sudo locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  de_DE.UTF-8...cannot open locale definition file `de_DE': No such file or directory
 done
Generation complete.
```

is there a way to remove and start over.. before i back up system and Reinstall?

Comment: Is it about Ubuntu?

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` ?